# How to position a div at the bottom of it's parent container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to position the two divs [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKXNr.png) at the bottom of their parent div. I have tried specifying this property in CSS:

```
position: absolute;
```

But it ends up overlapping and the buttons get mangled as well as [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVF6h.png). From what I understand absolute positioning would do this and my only choice would be to use JS.

This is what the html looks like:

```
<div id="box" class="box-192" style="border:1px solid #8c8c8c;padding:20px;">
  <h2>theLAO</h2>
  <div class="box-body">
    <p>A DOA supporting the Blockchain ecosystem.</p>
    <p>Twitter: <a href="https://twitter.com/TheLAOOfficial" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://twitter.com/TheLAOOfficial'); return false;">@TheLAOOfficial</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="button-div">
    <a href="https://thelao.io" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://thelao.io/'); return false;"><span class="buttons">visit theLAO ↗</span></a>
    <a href="https://daodir.co/doa/thelao/"><span class="buttons">discuss theLAO </span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

...and some relevant CSS

```
.button-div {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
bottom: 0;
padding-top: 25 px;
}
```

If you want to visit the site where this is happening, visit https://centinl.com

Comment: And where on the site is it happening, exactly?

Comment: Flex is your friend `#box { display: flex; } .box-body { flex-grow: 1; }` , no need for absolute position.

Comment: you can add padding to the bottom of each box of the height of your button container.

Comment: .box-192{
  position:relative;
}


.button-div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 25 px;
  position:absolute;
}

Comment: consider reading all the answers in the duplicate (I insist on *all*)

Answer (score 1):

Set your container to `display: flex;` and set the middle element with a `flex-grow` to 1 so it pushes its sibling elements to their extremities. There is no need to use `position: absolute;`.

```css
#box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
}

.box-body {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box-192" style="border:1px solid #8c8c8c;padding:20px;">
  <h2>theLAO</h2>
  <div class="box-body">
    <p>A DOA supporting the Blockchain ecosystem.</p>
    <p>Twitter: <a href="https://twitter.com/TheLAOOfficial" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://twitter.com/TheLAOOfficial'); return false;">@TheLAOOfficial</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="button-div">
    <a href="https://thelao.io" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://thelao.io/'); return false;"><span class="buttons">visit theLAO ↗</span></a>
    <a href="https://daodir.co/doa/thelao/"><span class="buttons">discuss theLAO </span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG that's great! Thank you!

Comment: Don't hesitate to mark this answer as the correct one thanks.